# Background worker progress percentage

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am adding string values to the listbox from List<>.
I want to calculate Progress Percentage in ReportProgress method.please help me to calculate progress percentage. I have written 0 in first parameter of ReportProgress method. I want to replace that 0 with progress percentage.

Here is my code.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     List<string> result = new List<string>();
     var found = obj.getFiles();

     foreach (var item in found)
     {
         if (item.Contains("SFTP:") || item.Contains("ERROR:"))
         {
             result.Add(item);

             (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0, item);
         }
         else
             (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(0);
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

     }
     e.Result = result;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState != null)
        listBox1.Items.Add(e.UserState);

    progressBar2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Systems.Collections.Generics.List<>

Comment: Let's say I have 100 items. I am currently on the 7th item. What progress have I made? How might you apply that to your code?

Comment: @PoojaJamdade "ReportProgress(0, item);" doesnt seem like you understand what those parameters are for..  its simple maths if you have x items and you are n through them to work out a percentage.

Comment: the parameters are int percentProgress and object userState. i want to calculate progress percentage

Comment: something like (current item/ total items in listbox) * 100

Comment: @pooh Multiply by 100 **before** the division.

Comment: `and object userState` You don't want to pass that parameter. Just the number.

Comment: The other wider problem you will have with your logic is that the loop will be **blazingly** fast. It is only slow because of the `Thread.Sleep`. If you removed that, there would be no need for setting the progress inside the loop, since it would run in milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreach is not necessarily the best iteration for this application. Use a for-loop and use the index to calculate the progress based on the size of found.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < found.Count; i++)
     {
         int progress = (int)(((float)(i + 1) / found.Count) * 100);
         if (found[i].Contains("SFTP:") || found[i].Contains("ERROR:"))
         {
             result.Add(found[i]);

             (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progress, found[i]);
         }
         else
             (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(progress);
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);    
     }
```

Comment: You're welcome! In general only use foreach if the iterated element's position in the collection is not of interest.

Comment: Yes! Thank you again!